# Azure / U-SQL - ROUND a number

Tags: azure, rounding, u-sql

I am trying to ROUND the SUM() of a float column in U-SQL but keep getting errors.

1) Is there a function that does this?

2) What kind of data can I pass it (ie int, float, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the C# scalar expressions. Thus `Math.Round` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) would be the appropriate operation.

Comment: An example of using Round and U-SQL can be seen at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621316.aspx#usingRound